# Unable to extract URL names from table using Selenium webdriver

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I have a table like below:

[image]

The goal is to extract the names using selenium webdriver.

I tried using the below code to fetch the  names using xpath:

```
wd = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver',chrome_options=chrome_options)
wd.get("https://www.deakin.edu.au/information-technology/staff-listing")

names = wd.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="table09355"]/tbody/tr[1]/td/a').text
```

The output appears as empty i.e `''`. How can I extract the names names using xpath in selenium webdriver ? The names are URL hyper-links.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to use below xpath :

```
//a[contains(@href,'https://')]
```

and use `find_elements` to store all anchor tag in a list like this :

```
for names in wd.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//a[contains(@href,'https://')]")
    print(names.text)
```

**Update 1 :**

```
driver.maximize_window()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
driver.get('https://www.deakin.edu.au/information-technology/staff-listing')
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "popup-accept"))).click()
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Emeritus Professors']")))).perform()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Emeritus Professors']"))).click()
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[contains(text(), 'Emeritus Professors')]/ancestor::h3/following-sibling::div/descendant::a")))).perform()
for names in driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//span[contains(text(), 'Emeritus Professors')]/ancestor::h3/following-sibling::div/descendant::a"):
    print(names.text)
```

**O/P :**

```
Emeritus Professor Lynn Batten
Emeritus Professor Andrzej Goscinski

Process finished with exit code 0
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

If you want to run on Google colab, try the below code :

```
!pip install selenium
!apt-get update 
!apt install chromium-chromedriver

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
wd = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver',chrome_options=chrome_options)
driver =webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver',chrome_options=chrome_options)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
driver.get("https://www.deakin.edu.au/information-technology/staff-listing")
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "popup-accept"))).click()
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Emeritus Professors']")))).perform()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Emeritus Professors']"))).click()
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[contains(text(), 'Emeritus Professors')]/ancestor::h3/following-sibling::div/descendant::a")))).perform()
for names in driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//span[contains(text(), 'Emeritus Professors')]/ancestor::h3/following-sibling::div/descendant::a"):
    print(names.text)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you show with an example using above code ? I'm still unable to get as I'm new to this

Comment: @user3046211 : Update the code under Update 1 section

Comment: Got it, But I'm getting time out exception when I run your code. Did you get such exceptions ?

Comment: Did you get such exceptions ?  - No it's just working fine on my local. Can you paste the error stack trace here ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233641/discussion-between-user3046211-and-cruisepandey).

Comment: I have posted the stack trace in the chat as it;s too long to be pasted here

Comment: @user3046211 : I ran the newly updated code on Google colab it worked.. try it out and let me know if you have any more concerns. Thank you !

Comment: Ah ! Is it ? Let me try on Colab once again

Comment: It worked in Google Colab too ! Not sure why it was showing time out exception earlier. Do you suggest to put an exception handler for handling exceptions like TimeOutException ? Thank you !

Comment: Yes exception handling is suggested